# mongoose findOne function return undefine

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I know we have lots of questions like this in here, but none of the answers seems to work on my code, take a look:

```
establishment = mongoose.model('Establishment' , new Schema({
    //_id : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name : String,
    cnpj : String,
    description : String,
    address : String,
    products : [],
    isActive : {type: Boolean, default: true}
}));




app.get('/home',(req, res)=>{
    var a = establishment.findOne({_id : "57d83a867d3ba20fcb657dc7" } , (err, estab)=>{
        if(err){
            return err;
        }
        console.log("inside the function: "+estab.name);
        return estab
    });
    console.log("outside the function: "+a.name)
})
```

when any output is given inside the findOne() function, it all work out just fine, but when i return it, just says it's "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

It's happening due to the non-blocking,asynchronous nature of node js.
This means any activity taking a long time to finish, such as file access, network communication, and database operations, are requested and put aside until the results are ready and returned via a callback function.

That's why you getting undefined, because while the db operation is happing the outer console get executed due to  non-blocking nature.

To get the result you can do this

```
app.get('/home',(req, res)=>{
    establishment.findOne({_id : "57d83a867d3ba20fcb657dc7" } , (err, estab)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.send(err);
        }
        console.log("inside the function: "+estab.name);
        // what ever proccing you need to do with result do here and finally return res
        res.json(estab)
    });
})
```